# Place 2 Boxes [div's] side by side

Tags: html, css, distance

I want to place the two boxes at the bottom of [link](http://tekkkz.com), the both article-boxes (div.content), side by side like you see, but without the big distance between them. How to fix this?

Here is relevant code :

```css
div.content {
    text-align: justify;
    color: #939393;
    padding: 25px 90px;
    margin: 0px auto 45px;
    width: 960px;
    border: 2px solid #F27F0E;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-small" style="float: left;">

    <h2></h2>
    <ol class="posts"></ol>

</div>
<div class="content-small" style="float: right;">

    <h2></h2>
    <ol class="posts"></ol>

</div>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant (minimal, [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)) code in your question. Don't rely on external sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply float left to both boxes and set your margin-right to appropriate value.

delete style from this :

```
<div class="content-small" style="float: left;"></div>
<div class="content-small" style="float: right;"></div>
```

so that they become :

```
<div class="content-small"></div>
<div class="content-small"></div>
```

and then change your css like this:

```
div.content-small {
    text-align: justify;
    color: #939393;
    padding: 25px 50px;
    margin: 0px auto 45px;
    width: 450px;
    border: 2px solid #F27F0E;
    float:left;        /* add this */
    margin-right:40px; /* add this and change value acc */
}
```

You can also try placing margin on each box separately to achieve your desired result

Comment: Still wont work, see Tekkkz.com , now the two boxes aren't centered

Comment: @MartinFischer what dosen't works. I've tried editing your live site using firefox dev tools , it does works. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: It works, sorry for my bad comment. But the two boxes are - like you can see at Tekkkz.com - not centered. Why not?

Comment: @MartinFischer see there are two methods to make them centered. If you want them centered at every resolution then make your site responsive , otherwise at current state you'll have to modify and play with margin values , like try `margin:0 55px;` or you can introduce additional html tags to enclose these two , to maintain your design.

Comment: Responsive sounds geat - but im not a web-dev, i just need this little site - how to make it responsive? I think all other boxes are already responsive

Comment: @MartinFischer you can either wrap them in a single container , or use a full-fledged responsive framework to do that task. What do you want? I can edit my answer as accordingly. and currently your site is not responsive. Certain blocks are cut when size is reduced , or as is seen by firefox dev tools.

Comment: ahh ya ok, i want that the both boxes are centered but not with a fixed value but like i centered the others, with margin auto and so on...

Comment: @MartinFischer you want your boxes to be centered ( not just these 2 but all boxes on your page) no matter what device the website is viewed on , ie. they should not have a particular fixed value . Am i getting you right? Then you'll have to use a responsive solution my friend. Otherwise these are dirty hacks , they will cut your text when site is viewed on other browsers.

Comment: @MartinFischer you don't necessarily have to be a web dev to do this task. Your website's design is minimal and it will be done in minutes. You just need to apply margin to each box while making their width : 100% and not just any fix value.Use % wherever you can .You can accept an answer for this question and ask another question with that responsive details if you want. I highly doubt that'll be difficult.

Comment: Could you - please - make my site responsive and clear-coded for me without get payed? Please, you said it is possible todo this in minutes ;)

Comment: Didn't received an email yet ... ?

Comment: got it - why'd you left the live chat?

Answer (score 2):

Using inline styles (putting the style tag inside of the element) is never a good thing, it's best practice to keep everything in a separate stylesheet and a lot more practical too.

In regards to your question you pretty much have the code already in your stylesheet, just remove the inline styles and put the both divs inside of a parent div.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content-bottom">
    <div class="content-small"></div>
    <div class="content-small"></div>
</div>
```

Now we just need to add a little css to center everything with your current layout.

**CSS:**

```
.content-bottom {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1144px;
}
```

You're probably going to want to adjust the widths and margins for the content-small classes now to your preference.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

create a wrapper for these 2 div

```
<div class="wrapper-new" style="margin:0 auto; width:...px;">
         <div class="content-small" style="float: left;">...</div>
         <div class="content-small" style="float: right;">...</div>    
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding an enclosing div around the two article boxes like below. Setting its width to 1144px matches with the total width of the content boxes above.

```
<div style="width: 1144px; margin: 0 auto 0 auto">
  <div class="content-small" style="float: left;">
     ...
  </div>
  <div class="content-small" style="float: right;">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

![enter image description here][1]

This is how you need to do it. The bottom two article boxes should be inside a div with fixed width 1144px and both content-small should be float:left, 2nd one with a margin-left:36px;

That's it! Run the code snippet in `Full page` and you can see your desired result.

NB: I've removed jQuery from the snippet. If you find my answer useful please mark it as accepted. Thanks! :)

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #1A1A1A;
}
div.content {
  text-align: justify;
  color: #939393;
  padding: 25px 90px;
  margin: 0 auto 45px auto;
  width: 960px;
  border: 2px solid #F27F0E;
}
div.bottom-content {
  padding: 25px 0;
  margin: 0 auto 45px auto;
  width: 1144px;
}
div.content-small {
  text-align: justify;
  color: #939393;
  padding: 25px 50px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 450px;
  border: 2px solid #F27F0E;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #6B6B6B;
}
a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #F27F0E;
}
dt {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  color: #bbb;
}
img {
  border: 1px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.1);
}
div.date {
  width: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  margin-left: -120px;
  float: left;
}
div.date p {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
div.center {
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto 45px auto;
}
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  margin: 0 1em;
}
#github {
  background-color: #4183c4;
  background-image: url(http://tekkkz.com/css/github.png);
}
#twitter {
  background-color: #00aced;
  background-image: url(http://tekkkz.com/css/twitter.png);
}
.posts,
.posts li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.posts li {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.title {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.date {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #bbb;
}
h1 {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
h2,
h3 {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 10px 0;
  color: #fff;
}
footer {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="author" content="Martin Fischer">
  <meta name="description" content="Personal Profile of Tekkkz (Martin Fischer)">
  <meta name="keywords" content="pc, personal, profile, web, tekkkz, microcontroller, programming, gaming, avr, atml, s4, s4league, aeriagames, english, german">
  <meta name="robots" content="FOLLOW,INDEX">

  <title>Tekkkz - Personal Profile</title>

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Tekkkz (Martin Fischer)</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="center">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/Tekkkz_" title="Twitter" class="icon" id="twitter" target="_blank">Twitter</a>
    <a href="https://github.com/Tekkkz" title="GitHub" class="icon" id="github" target="_blank">GitHub</a>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <h2>ABOUT</h2>
    <dl>
      <dt><img src="http://tekkkz.com/css/profile.jpg" alt="profile" height="135em" /></dt>
      <dd>
        <p>I am Martin Fischer, otherwise known online as Tekkkz. I am 17 years old and currently a student at the 'Winckelmann Gymnasium Stendal'.</p>
        <p>My educational interests include mathematics and science, especially physics and chemistry. My extracurricular interests include everything that has to do with electronics, from simple soldering up to programming microcontrollers and develop complex
          PCB's, general programming in C and C++ as well as linux and servers.</p>
        <p>See my <a href="./cv.pdf" target="_blank">CV</a>.</p>
      </dd>
      <dl>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <h2>CONTACT</h2>
    <dl>
      <dt>Email</dt>
      <dd>martin@Tekkkz.com</dd>

      <dt>IRC</dt>
      <dd>Tekkkz on Freenode</dd>

      <dt>ICQ</dt>
      <dd>ICQ Number: 612184097</dd>
    </dl>
  </div>

  <div class="bottom-content">
    <div class="content-small" style="float: left;">
      <h2>ARTICLES</h2>
      <ol class="posts">
        <li>
          <a href="./posts/2015-02-06-euzebox-with-atmega1284.html" target="_blank" class="title">&ldquo;EUzebox with ATmega1284&rdquo;</a>
          <span class="date">&mdash;February 06, 2015</span>
          <br />
          <span class="description">Instruction set to build an EUzebox with an ATmega1284</span>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="content-small" style="float: left; margin-left:36px;">
      <h2>ARTICLES</h2>
      <ol class="posts">
        <li>
          <a href="./posts/2015-02-06-euzebox-with-atmega1284.html" target="_blank" class="title">&ldquo;EUzebox with ATmega1284&rdquo;</a>
          <span class="date">&mdash;February 06, 2015</span>
          <br />
          <span class="description">Instruction set to build an EUzebox with an ATmega1284</span>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you please remove the screenshot? Ty